# AWK: Merge columns in a CSV file

Tags: awk, merge, gawk

The file is sorted by the column 7, and it needs to combine fields 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 and 16, for each group of lines with the same ID, which is the value of the column 7.

> I finally solved my problem alone, thanks to all!!.

```
What I have done:

BEGIN{
    FS="\t"
    x="\"\"";
 } 

(NR !=1){
        for(i=11;i<=16;i++)
        { 
            if($i!= x)
            {
                k=match(a[$7], $i);
                if (k == 0)
                {
                    a[$7]=a[$7]"\t"$i;
                }
            }
        }

        b[$7]=b[$7]"|"$17"\t"$18"\t"$19"\t"$20;
        c[$7]=c[$7]"|"$1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8"\t"$9"\t"$10;
    }

END{
    for ( g in a)
    {
        t=split(a[g], A, "\t");
        for (y=t; y<7; y++)
        {
            a[g]=a[g]"\t"x;
        }

        mx=split(b[g], B, "|");
        mt=split(c[g], C, "|");
# From here, it's where I have the problem. I don't know how to square the values of the variables for the next two loops. So the lines are not duplicated
        for (i=2; i<=mx; i++)
        {
            print C[i]"\t"a[g]"\t"B[i];
        } # Here I left over a "for{}" loop
    }
}
```

Input CSV File:

```
    subtype idproject   qvnqsa  country lang    id  idkey   vbt_type    brand_reco  dealer_reco M1  M2  M3  M4  M5  M6  verbatim    Edited  Translated  Category    keywords    
V   voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460100" **"027460100expe"** "expe"  "9" "9" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak."             
VP  voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460100" **"027460100expe"** "expe"  "9" "9" "VP001" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "VP001" "aanpak,aangename"      
VP  voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460100" **"027460100expe"** "expe"  "9" "9" "VP001" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "VP001" "aanpak,persoonlijke"       
VP  voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460100" **"027460100expe"** "expe"  "9" "9" "VP001" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "VP001" "luisteren"     
VP  voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460100" **"027460100expe"** "expe"  "9" "9" "VP001" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "VP001" "nemen,tijd"        
VP  voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460100" **"027460100expe"** "expe"  "9" "9" "VP001" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "VP024" "super"     
V   voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460103" **"027460103expe"** "expe"  "9" "9" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Ok"    "Ok"    "Ok"                
VP  voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460103" **"027460103expe"** "expe"  "9" "9" "VP024" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Ok"    "Ok"    "Ok"    "VP024" "Ok"
```

> What I get with my script. In the output lines are doubled.

```
subtype idproject   qvnqsa  country lang    id  idkey   vbt_type    brand_reco  dealer_reco M1  M2  M3  M4  M5  M6  verbatim    Edited  Translated  Category    keywords    
V   voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460100" **"027460100expe"** "expe"  "9" "9" "VP001" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak."             
VP  voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460100" **"027460100expe"** "expe"  "9" "9" "VP001" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "VP001" "aanpak,aangename"      
VP  voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460100" **"027460100expe"** "expe"  "9" "9" "VP001" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "VP001" "aanpak,persoonlijke"       
VP  voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460100" **"027460100expe"** "expe"  "9" "9" "VP001" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "VP001" "luisteren"     
VP  voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460100" **"027460100expe"** "expe"  "9" "9" "VP001" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "VP001" "nemen,tijd"        
VP  voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460100" **"027460100expe"** "expe"  "9" "9" "VP001" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "VP024" "super" 
V   voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460100" **"027460100expe"** "expe"  "9" "9" "VP001" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak."             
VP  voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460100" **"027460100expe"** "expe"  "9" "9" "VP001" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "VP001" "aanpak,aangename"      
VP  voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460100" **"027460100expe"** "expe"  "9" "9" "VP001" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "VP001" "aanpak,persoonlijke"       
VP  voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460100" **"027460100expe"** "expe"  "9" "9" "VP001" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "VP001" "luisteren"     
VP  voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460100" **"027460100expe"** "expe"  "9" "9" "VP001" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "VP001" "nemen,tijd"        
VP  voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460100" **"027460100expe"** "expe"  "9" "9" "VP001" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "VP024" "super" 

V   voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460103" **"027460103expe"** "expe"  "9" "9" "VP024" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Ok"    "Ok"    "Ok"                
VP  voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460103" **"027460103expe"** "expe"  "9" "9" "VP024" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Ok"    "Ok"    "Ok"    "VP024" "Ok"
V   voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460103" **"027460103expe"** "expe"  "9" "9" "VP024" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Ok"    "Ok"    "Ok"                
VP  voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460103" **"027460103expe"** "expe"  "9" "9" "VP024" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Ok"    "Ok"    "Ok"    "VP024" "Ok"
```

Expected output:

```
subtype idproject   qvnqsa  country lang    id  idkey   vbt_type    brand_reco  dealer_reco M1  M2  M3  M4  M5  M6  verbatim    Edited  Translated  Category    keywords    
V   voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460100" **"027460100expe"** "expe"  "9" "9" "VP001" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak."             
VP  voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460100" **"027460100expe"** "expe"  "9" "9" "VP001" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "VP001" "aanpak,aangename"      
VP  voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460100" **"027460100expe"** "expe"  "9" "9" "VP001" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "VP001" "aanpak,persoonlijke"       
VP  voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460100" **"027460100expe"** "expe"  "9" "9" "VP001" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "VP001" "luisteren"     
VP  voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460100" **"027460100expe"** "expe"  "9" "9" "VP001" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "VP001" "nemen,tijd"        
VP  voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460100" **"027460100expe"** "expe"  "9" "9" "VP001" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "Van het eerste moment tot het laatste moment een super-service! Ze luisteren, nemen hun tijd. Een zeer persoonlijke aangename aanpak." "VP024" "super"     
V   voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460103" **"027460103expe"** "expe"  "9" "9" "VP024" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Ok"    "Ok"    "Ok"                
VP  voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460103" **"027460103expe"** "expe"  "9" "9" "VP024" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "Ok"    "Ok"    "Ok"    "VP024" "Ok"
```

Input:

```
ID    A     B     C        D    E    F    G    H
1     "9"   "9"   "Vp25"   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""
1     "9"   "9"   "Vp34"   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""
1     "9"   "9"   "Vp98"   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""
2     "9"   "9"   "Ap45"   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""
2     "9"   "9"   "Ap66"   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""
```

Expected Output:

```
ID    A     B     C        D        E        F    G    H
1     "9"   "9"   "Vp25"   "Vp34"   "Vp98"   ""   ""   ""
1     "9"   "9"   "Vp25"   "Vp34"   "Vp98"   ""   ""   ""
1     "9"   "9"   "Vp25"   "Vp34"   "Vp98"   ""   ""   ""
2     "9"   "9"   "Ap45"   "Ap66"   ""   ""   ""   ""
2     "9"   "9"   "Ap45"   "Ap66"   ""   ""   ""   ""
```

Comment: tl;dr. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Is the problem that I have outlined understood? Any help?

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks for the link. Can you help?

Comment: No. Too many columns. I cannot see what's different. Come up with a minimal dataset that demonstrates the problem

Comment: @glennjackman The difference is in column 7 it's between two asterisks. The values of the column 7 are the reference index for the arrays.Another thing is that you don't feel seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update after clarification of question**:
For all occurrences of a key (value in a certain column), the different values in another column have to be collected and be inserted in a range of columns for each line with this key:
Let's say, our tab-separated `inputFile` looks like this

```
ID  A   B   C       D   E   F   G   H
1   "9" "9" "Vp25"  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
1   "9" "9" "Vp34"  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
1   "9" "9" "Vp98"  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
2   "9" "9" "Ap45"  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
2   "9" "9" "Ap66"  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
```

and its first column serves as key. Then, the task is to fill columns C-G with all different values found in, for example, column C for a key:

```
ID  A   B   C       D       E       F   G   H
1   "9" "9" "Vp25"  "Vp34"  "Vp98"  ""  ""  ""
1   "9" "9" "Vp25"  "Vp34"  "Vp98"  ""  ""  ""
1   "9" "9" "Vp25"  "Vp34"  "Vp98"  ""  ""  ""
2   "9" "9" "Ap45"  "Ap66"  ""  ""  ""  ""
2   "9" "9" "Ap45"  "Ap66"  ""  ""  ""  ""
```

This can be achieved with the following awk-script:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"; key=1; aggregate=4; to=8;}
    NR==FNR{
        if($aggregate != "\"\"") {
            a[$key] = a[$key]$aggregate""OFS
            b[$key] = b[$key] +1
        }
    }
    NR!=FNR{
    if(FNR == 1) {print $0}
    else {
        line = ""
        for(i=1;i<aggregate;i++) {
            line = line""$i""OFS;
        }
        line = line""a[$key]
        for(i = aggregate+b[$key]; i<=to; i++){line= line"\"\""OFS}
        for(i=to+1; i<NF; i++) {
            line = line""$i""OFS
        }
        line = line""$NF
    print line
    }
}' inputFile inputFile
```

Note that the inputFile is added twice to the call! Moreover, in the `BEGIN{...}` section, the index of the column containing the key (`key`), the index of the column to aggregate data `aggregate` and the index of the column that represents the end of the range have to be specified

Comment: @Criatos: Example works for me, if I understood your problem correctly. Why is your output incorrect? Can you provide an example.  There is one assumption that I copied from your example: "empty" fields 11-16 are supposed to be equal to `""` (and the first line is assumed to be a header, i.e., it is not evaluated)

Comment: I added a clearer example. With the input and expected output.

Comment: @Polucho: Does this answer your question?